# 0n_rreaction_add donest trigger properly

Tags: discord.py, bots, payload

I am trying to create a bot for limited pin. something like pinboard. bot works only for latest messages. doesn't work for older.

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.guild_reactions = True
intents.message_content = True
intents.messages = True
intents.typing = True

async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
if reaction.emoji == pin_emoji:
    channel = reaction.message.channel
    message = reaction.message

    # Ignore reactions from the bot or pinned messages
    if user.bot or message.pinned:
        return

    content = message.content
    attachment_url = ""
    if message.attachments:
        attachment_url = message.attachments[0].url

    message_link = message.jump_url

    embed = discord.Embed()
    filename_without_extension = message.attachments[0].filename.split(".")[0] if message.attachments else "No File"
    value = f"[{filename_without_extension}]({message_link})\n{content}"
    embed = discord.Embed(description=value)
    embed.set_image(url=attachment_url)

    pinboard_channel = bot.get_channel(pinboard_channel_id)
    embed_msg = await pinboard_channel.send(embed=embed)
    await embed_msg.add_reaction(pin_emoji)

    # Store the pinned message ID in the dictionary
    pinned_messages[message.id] = embed_msg.id
```

I triey the payload and many other thing problem still remains the same

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation,

Called when a message has a reaction added to it. Similar to `on_message_edit()`, **if the message is not found in the internal message cache, then this event will not be called**.

So consider using `on_raw_reaction_add()` instead.

[Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_raw_reaction_add)